# Drawing table-like nodes uing Graphviz

Tags: python, graphviz

Is there a way in graphviz - python to draw a column of rectangular nodes, like this:
[image]

I want each rectangle as node since these nodes are generated from a previous code where I already drew a tree of nodes.

[image]

I have created my nodes using this command

```
 tree.node(Taskstr+str(ID))
```

Answer (score 1):

The Python code will depend on which library you are using to call Graphviz, but whichever one you use, you want to set the node `shape=record` and the label to contain the items of the record between curly braces ('{}') with pipe ('|') characters between each row.

Here's what the `dot` file will look like for your first example:

```
digraph structs {
    n1 [shape=record label="{  |  |  | Task#2 | Task#1 }"]
}
```

which renders as:

[image: record node example]

Comment: thanks, but is there an API to generate the dot file you made, i/ mean something like  tree.node("Node A") where tree is the graph name

Comment: Are you currently using any of the libraries such as [pydotplus](https://pydotplus.readthedocs.io/), [pygraphviz](https://pygraphviz.github.io/), of [graphviz](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)? Any of these will allow you to define the tree structure, but you will need to write some code to make the label.

Comment: In graphviz you can set the label when you define a node as `tree.node("Node A", shape="record", label="{  |  |  | Task#2 | Task#1 }")`.

Comment: great is there another function to push Task#2 and Task#1 into the node, because I dont want to hardcode it, it depends on a text file

Comment: The label is just a string. Use the string formatting operations to programatically create the string from your data. I can't really be of much more help unless you post some code that shows where you are getting stuck.

Comment: is there a graphviz function to remove a node?

Comment: @KaramAboGhalieh not that I know of. I think that is a shortcoming of the python graphviz library. Take a look at pydotplus, which has functions to delete nodes and edges.